# Couchdb, how do I get a unique list of the second element in key?

Tags: couchdb, unique

my view looks like this:

For a given value of `session`, I want to retrieve a unique list of `type`.

```
function (doc) {
 if (doc.sesion) {
    emit([doc.sesion, doc.type], doc);
 }
}
```

How should I query the view? Do I need to create another view?

I am aware that I should use include_docs instead of emitting the doc in the view, but lets not worry about that for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like that:

```
?startkey=["session_value",""]&endkey=["session_value",{}]
```

However, it would be easier to reformat your view like that:

```
function (doc) {
 if (doc.sesion) {
    emit(doc.sesion, doc.type);
 }
}
```

And query as you mentioned with:

```
?key="session_value"&include_docs=true
```

Comment: In case doc.type can have null value then query would be: ?startkey=["session_value",null]&endkey=["session_value",{}]

Answer (score 0):

To get the unique set of types you can use `reduce`, querying the view with `group=true` without `group_level` (or `group_level=exact`, see [view API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options)) and `startkey=["YOUR_SESSION"]&endkey=["YOUR_SESSION",{}]` as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_Snippets#Generating_a_list_of_unique_values). Note that this way you cannot use `include_docs` because you can use it with `map` only (without the `reduce`).